# How to get edited subitem index of list control in MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I'm writing a dialog based MFC application on Visual Studio 2017 in C++.

In the dialog I have a list control. I want to know which column the user changes if he edits the list.

the list control looks like this:

[image]

So if I edit the cell `Channel Mode B` I expect the value of the cell to be row = 2 and col = 1. I've tried using the following code:

In the `mask` field of `LVCOLUMN` I've enabled the following flag:

```
LVCOLUMN lvColumn;
lvColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_SUBITEM;
```

In the `MESSAGE_MAP` I've added the following notification:

`ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, IDC_LIST1, &CEditableListControlDlg::OnLvnItemchangedList1)`

and the handler I've written is:

```
void CEditableListControlDlg::OnLvnItemchangedList1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);
    
    
    
    if (pNMLV->uChanged & LVIF_STATE)
    {
        
        if ((pNMLV->uNewState) & LVIS_SELECTED)
        {
            int iItem = pNMLV->iItem;
            int subItem = pNMLV->iSubItem;
        }
    }
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

In this code the variable `iItem` is the row selected and `subItem` is the column selected.
What interests me is to get the `pNMLV->iSubItem`. My problem is that the value of the `subItem` variable is always zero, which mean it hasn't been selected by Microsoft Docs Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/ns-richedit-nmhdr)

How can I get the index of the sub-item which been edited?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the rationale behind abusing the list control like this? The information you are trying to represent really wants an array of check boxes. Those are switches the user can toggle, which is the most natural way to describe the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select a different line, the message will respond. If you select the same row and different columns, the message will not respond repeatedly. So, the `iSubItem` will be always 0 when you only change the column.

You could refer to the following example.

```
void CSdfsdfDlg::OnItemchangedList1(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
    NM_LISTVIEW* pNMListView = (NM_LISTVIEW*)pNMHDR;
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
     
    if ((pNMListView-> uChanged   &   LVIF_STATE)   &&   (pNMListView-> uNewState   &   LVIS_SELECTED)) 
    {
        DWORD   dwPos =GetMessagePos(); 
        CPoint   point(LOWORD(dwPos),HIWORD(dwPos)); 
         
        m_lst.ScreenToClient(&point);   
         
        LVHITTESTINFO lvinfo; 
        lvinfo.pt = point; 
        lvinfo.flags = LVHT_ABOVE; 
         
        int  nItem = m_lst.SubItemHitTest(&lvinfo); 
        if(nItem!=-1) 
        { 
            CString strtemp; 
            strtemp.Format( "the row is %d and the column is %d ", lvinfo.iItem, lvinfo.iSubItem); 
            MessageBox(strtemp);
        } 
         
    }
 
 
    *pResult = 0;
}
```